# Problem converting str to date in python when locale is set to pt-Br

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, locale, python-datetime

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
import locale
from datetime import datetime

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "pt-BR") # Windows

#### doing stuff with locale (like converting number 1.000,00)
#####

date_str = '29/12/2017' # The date - 29 Dec 2017
format_str = '%d/%m/%Y' # The format


datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, format_str)
```

with only this small code I get the following error:

> ---
>
> ValueError
>   Traceback (most recent call last)  in ()
>        11
>        12
>   ---> 13 datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, format_str)
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib_strptime.py in ()
>       278 # DO NOT modify _TimeRE_cache or _regex_cache without acquiring the cache lock
>       279 # first!
>   --> 280 _TimeRE_cache = TimeRE()
>       281 _CACHE_MAX_SIZE = 5 # Max number of regexes stored in _regex_cache
>       282 _regex_cache = {}
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib_strptime.py in **init**(self,
>   locale_time)
>       192             self.locale_time = locale_time
>       193         else:
>   --> 194             self.locale_time = LocaleTime()
>       195         base = super()
>       196         base.**init**({
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib_strptime.py in **init**(self)
>        70
>        71         """
>   ---> 72         self.lang = _getlang()
>        73         self.__calc_weekday()
>        74         self.__calc_month()
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib_strptime.py in _getlang()
>        29 def _getlang():
>        30     # Figure out what the current language is set to.
>   ---> 31     return locale.getlocale(locale.LC_TIME)
>        32
>        33 class LocaleTime(object):
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\locale.py in
>   getlocale(category)
>       579     if category == LC_ALL and ';' in localename:
>       580         raise TypeError('category LC_ALL is not supported')
>   --> 581     return _parse_localename(localename)
>       582
>       583 def setlocale(category, locale=None):
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\locale.py in
>   _parse_localename(localename)
>       488     elif code == 'C':
>       489         return None, None
>   --> 490     raise ValueError('unknown locale: %s' % localename)
>       491
>       492 def _build_localename(localetuple):
>
> **ValueError: unknown locale: pt-BR**

Any clue how to solve this issue?

I am running Windows, Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```py
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "pt_br")
```

Comment: In [9]: locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "pt_br")

Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-9529345bc0a3> in <module>()
----> 1 locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "pt_br")

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\locale.py in setlocale(category, locale)
    596         # convert to string
    597         locale = normalize(_build_localename(locale))
--> 598     return _setlocale(category, locale)
    599
    600 def resetlocale(category=LC_ALL):

Error: unsupported locale setting

Answer (score 2):

On Windows go to

Control Panel -> Clock and Region -> Region -> Administrative (tab) -> Change system locale (Button) -> change the language to Portuguese (Brazil) -> restart the machine

Now on your code set the locale to

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt-BR.UTF-8')

I was with the same problem like you. My mistake was the lack of ".UTF-8" on the language name.

Comment: well, to properly work I had to use "pt_BR.UTF-8".

Thank you!